# FFMPEG, command with Overlay and Drawtext on video

Tags: android, ffmpeg, overlay, drawtext

I have 2 commands, one for overlay(work alone), one for add text (work alone), i want this 2 commands in one.

`ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex [0:v][1:v]overlay=5:5,drawtext=fontfile=:text=mytext:fontcolor=orange@1.0:fontsize=30:x=30:y=200[v] -map [output] output.mp4`

This command generate empty file without error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your `-map` option is using a label that does not reference anything.

You should be getting this error:

```
Output with label 'output' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere.
```

The `-filter_complex` output and the [`-map` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) should use the same label. It can be almost any arbitrary name as long as they match. Also, your `fontfile` is missing the font path. You may have to quote your `text` string, but you're using Android and it is weird with quoting. Lastly, you should [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the audio.

Use this: both filter output and `-map` are using `[v]`

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex [0:v][1:v]overlay=5:5,drawtext=text=mytext:fontcolor=orange@1.0:fontsize=30:x=30:y=200[v] -map [v] -map 0:a -c:a copy output.mp4
```

or this: both filter output and `-map` are using `[output]`

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex [0:v][1:v]overlay=5:5,drawtext=text=mytext:fontcolor=orange@1.0:fontsize=30:x=30:y=200[output] -map [output] -map 0:a -c:a copy output.mp4
```

or this: use the [default stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection)

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex [0:v][1:v]overlay=5:5,drawtext=text=mytext:fontcolor=orange@1.0:fontsize=30:x=30:y=200 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help.
I tried : `-i, 15500649730000.mp4, -i, 12.png, -filter_complex, [0:v][1:v]overlay=10:10,drawtext=fontfile=MarkerFelt.ttf:text=mytext:fontcolor=orange@1.0:fontsize=30:x=30:y=200[output], -map, [output], -c:a, copy, 15500649730000.mp4` , i remove 0:a because i have no sound. Not working, no error and generate a file of 48 bytes.

Comment: @Cleoh Show the complete log from the `ffmpeg` process.

Comment: I think the problem is not the command because the process stops before it's over. 
` E/DEBUGG:       cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
 E/DEBUGG: frame=   13 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
 E/DEBUGG: frame=   34 fps= 33 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
 E/DEBUGG: frame=   47 fps= 14 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x`

Comment: Can't add complete logs, too many chars, i post only the end.

Comment: @Cleoh Unfortunately that is not informative. Instead of trying to cram everything into comments you can use a pastebin site and provide the link in a comment.

Comment: I used the third solution on another video and it works. 
I do not know why it does not work for the first video.
I will test with 2 overlays and 1 text, i hope it will work too.

Comment: @Cleoh Unknown. Without the actual command and the complete log only guesses can be made but there are multiple possibilities of failure.

Comment: I finally found why the process stopped. Android kill it.